# Wicked gem cannot find wedding ID in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wizard, wicked-gem

I'm trying to implement the 'Wicked' gem for wizards and cannot figure out this error for the life of me. Already referenced [Ryan bates railscast #346](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked) and the [step by step tutorial by schneems](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step).

I have 2 controllers: Weddings and Wedding_steps. The user initially creates a Wedding and after the create action is redirected to the Wedding_steps controller (which uses Wicked) to update the wedding model with additional info.

The wedding_id is successfully detected in the first step weddingdetails, but after submitting that step, I get the following error:

**ERROR**

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WeddingStepsController#update
>
> Couldn't find Wedding without an ID:
> app/controllers/wedding_steps_controller.rb:11:in `update'
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"utf8"=>"✓",
> "_method"=>"put",
> "authenticity_token"=>"JMd+8gf4rVqOSNMSFrKcD3WxK+X3zvYliSMWqTg0SkE=",
> "wedding"=>{"bridename"=>"",
> "groomname"=>"",
> "weddingdate"=>"",
> "weddingcity"=>"",
> "weddingstate"=>"",
> "url"=>""},
> "commit"=>"Next",
> "id"=>"wedding_id=11"}

It is supposed to continue to the next step `/wedding_steps/eventdetails?wedding_id=11` but instead gives the error and goes to `/wedding_steps/wedding_id=11`

Also of note is that without the Update action in place, the information successfully saves and redirects to the Wedding Show action.

Here is the relevant code:

**wedding_steps_controller.rb**

```
class WeddingStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :weddingdetails, :eventdetails

def show
    @wedding = Wedding.find(params[:wedding_id])
    render_wizard
end

def update
    @wedding = Wedding.find(params[:wedding_id])
    @wedding.update_attributes(params[:wedding])
    render_wizard @wedding
end

end
```

**weddings_controller.rb**

```
def create
@wedding = current_user.weddings.new(params[:wedding])


respond_to do |format|
  if @wedding.save
    format.html { redirect_to wedding_steps_path(:id => "weddingdetails", :wedding_id => @wedding.id) }
    format.json { render json: @wedding, status: :created, location: @wedding }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @wedding.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

**STEP 1: wedding_steps/weddingdetails.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@wedding, :url => wizard_path(wedding_id: @wedding.id), :method => :put, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<div class="form-inputs">


<div class="formrow center">
  <%= f.input :bridename, placeholder: "The Bride's Name", label: false %>
  <h2 class="inline">  &</h2>
  <%= f.input :groomname, placeholder: "The Groom's Name", label: false %>
</div>


<div class="formrow center">
  <%= f.text_field :weddingdate %> 
  <!-- OLD STYLE DATE FORMAT <%= f.input :weddingdate, label: "Wedding Date" %> -->
  <%= f.input :weddingcity, label: "City" %>
  <%= f.input :weddingstate, label: "State" %>
</div>


<div class="formrow center"> 
  <%= f.input :url, placeholder: "i.e. 'johnandkate' ", label: false %> 
</div>

</div>


<div class="form-actions center">
<%= f.button :submit, value: "Next" %>
</div>



<% end %>

<%= link_to 'skip', next_wizard_path(wedding_id: @wedding.id) %>
```

**STEP 2: wedding_steps/eventdetails.html.erb**

```
EVENT DETAILS STEP <!--PLACEHOLDER FOR NOW -->
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Jobshop::Application.routes.draw do    
    resources :pins
    resources :weddings
    resources :wedding_steps  

    get "users/show"

    root :to => 'pages#home'
    get 'about' => 'pages#about'

    devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

    resources :inviterequests


    devise_for :views
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

    devise_for :users
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

    match 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
```

Comment: When execute please post the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@wedding, :url => wizard_path, :method => :put, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
```

Should be:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@wedding, :url => wizard_path(wedding_id: @wedding.id), :method => :put, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
```

Note the `wizard_path(wedding_id: @wedding.id)` When you submit the form you should see `parameters = {:wedding_id => some_number}` in the logs.

Paste the output of the `params` for the update action if it doesn't work.

Edit:

You should have `":wedding_id"` as part of the required url this will make it impossible to even generate a link to that controller unless it has a properly formatted url.

Replace this

```
resources :wedding_steps
```

with this

```
  scope "weddings/:wedding_id" do
    resources :wedding_steps
  end
```

So now a correct url would look like `weddings/83/wedding_steps/weddingdetails`. Likely one or more of your view helpers isn't including wedding_id properly and with this new constraint you will raise an error in the view, but this is a good thing since it will show you where the malformed link is.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing in the params after update action. ID seems to work, but it's not recognizing the next step?
------>
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1MfI9JSd0RFoDhOYgxT1pxdouVShlwhI5dwJ4WG1NWQ=", "wedding"=>{"bridename"=>"Nisha", "groomname"=>"Arjun", "weddingdate"=>"", "weddingcity"=>"Houston", "weddingstate"=>"TX", "url"=>"arjunisha"}, "commit"=>"Next", "id"=>"wedding_id=83"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Wedding without an ID):
  app/controllers/wedding_steps_controller.rb:11:in 'update'`

Comment: try this instead:
:url => wizard_path(@wedding.id)

remove the wedding: @wedding.id part, it should just return the number now

Comment: tried that as well. it still doesn't seem to fix the issue of the next step not loading. any other ideas? is there anything wrong with the code in the controller Update action?

Comment: @Adim wicked hijacks the id part of the param.

Comment: @NishaDhingra to get this to work you need your params to look something like this
`{"id" => "weddingdetails", "wedding_id" => 83, "wedding"=>{"bridename"=>"Nisha", # ... }` The form should look something like this `<form action="/wedding_steps/weddingdetails?wedding_id=83"` I've never used wicked with simple_form

Comment: @Schneems, yep that's what i'm seeing on the first step of the wizard. When I hit next to go to the second step, it should be `<form action="/wedding_steps/eventdetails?wedding_id=83"` but instead just shows `<form action="/wedding_steps/83"` ..that's where i'm getting stuck on how to fix it.

Comment: After you submit the form the first time, it should render hit the update action then render `eventdetails.html.erb`, what does that form helper look like? Can you update your question? Also your "skip" link needs the `wedding_id` too.

Comment: Just updated the question w/more detailed error, routes file, and updated form. Sorry, I'm fairly new to rails and as far as i can tell there is no form helper. Can you glean anything new from these updates?

Comment: For your routes I recommend putting `":wedding_id"` into your scope. That way it will be impossible to even hit the controller without a properly formed URL. I updated my answer to include my suggestion of a scope.

Comment: Thx, that's helpful. Now I see the following. Trying to fix first line of update?
`Started PUT "/weddings/14/wedding_steps/wedding_id=14"` ...
`Processing by WeddingStepsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",` ... `"commit"=>"Next", "wedding_id"=>"14", "id"=>"wedding_id=14"}
  Wedding Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "weddings".* FROM "weddings" WHERE "weddings"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "14"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/weddings/14/wedding_steps/wicked_finish`

Comment: That is weird, wicked should be doing the right thing automatically for you, but you can force it to do the right thing by changing your path to this `wizard_path(step, wedding_id: @wedding.id)` which should force the :id to be the same as `step`

Answer (score -1):

I tried the solution provided by Schneems, however it is not running completely without errors. I implemented the following way.

Change

```
resources :wedding_steps
```

To

```
scope "weddings/:wedding_id" do
  resources :wedding_steps
end
```

The problem is parameters are displayed as forbidden based on the error that has been thrown as **ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError**

To get rid off this,

Change

```
def update
  @wedding = Wedding.find(params[:wedding_id])
  @wedding.update_attributes(params[:wedding])
  render_wizard @wedding
end
```

To

```
def update
  @wedding = Wedding.find(params[:wedding_id])
  @wedding.update_attributes(wedding_params)
  render_wizard @wedding
end

private 
def wedding_params
  params.require(:wedding).permit(........your parameters here.................)
end
```