# Find object by ID in Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

I've built a wizard in my rails 4 app using [Wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked). I've specifically followed [this guide](http://brains.rabid.co.nz/2014/09/29/rails-multistep-forms.html), the only difference is I'm doing this with a nested resource. I'm having difficulties with my controller actions that are supposed to find the object the form is building using its ID.

The current flow of the app is a user clicks a button that creates the object and is redirected to the first step of the wizard which updates the object throughout a series of steps. The problem is I'm not passing the object's ID through the parameters because I'm passing the wizard's step in the ID field.

**Button that creates object**

```
<%= link_to business_loan_application_path(@user), method: :post, :class => "btn btn-success" do %><% end
%>
```

**LoanApplication Controller**

```
    def create
      @user = current_user
      @loanapplication = @user.loan_applications.new
      @loanapplication.save(validate: false)
      redirect_to business_loan_application_wizard_path(@user.id,LoanApplication.form_steps.first)
    end
```

I need to somehow pass the :loan_application_id into the business_loan_application_wizard_path arguments.

**Error**

```
Couldn't find LoanApplication without an ID
```

LoanApplication belongs_to Business through has_many relationship.

```
{"business_id"=>"55", "id"=>"business_details"}
```

business_details is the first step in the wizard. These are the params that are passed when I first create the object via a button with a put request.

**Wizard Controller**

```
class WizardController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :require_business

  steps *LoanApplication.form_steps

  def show
    @business = current_user
    @loanapplication = LoanApplication.find(params[:loan_application_id])
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @business = current_user
    @loanapplication = @business.loan_applications.last
    @loanapplication.update_attributes(loan_application_params(step))
    render_wizard @loanapplication
  end
end
```

Comment: `routes.rb` would be really helpful here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175301/wicked-gem-cannot-find-wedding-id-in-update-action?rq=1) helped solve this problem.

Changed

```
resources :wizard
```

To

```
scope "loan_application/:loan_application_id" do
  resources :wizard
end
```

In my routes.rb file.

My Wizard controller is now the following:

```
def show
  @business = current_user
  @loanapplication = LoanApplication.find(params[:loan_application_id])
  render_wizard
end

def update
  @business = current_user
  @loanapplication = LoanApplication.find(params[:loan_application_id])
  @loanapplication.update_attributes(loan_application_params(step))
  render_wizard @loanapplication
end
```

Finally, the loan application controller redirect link has been changed:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @loanapplication = @user.loan_applications.new
  @loanapplication.save(validate: false)
  redirect_to business_loan_application_wizard_path(@user.id, LoanApplication.form_steps.first, :loan_application_id => @loanapplication.id) 
end
```